# Source of Azure VM Network Traffic

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I can see the quantity of network traffic on my Azure virtual machine using the metrics blade. But I'd like to know where that traffic comes from.  Is there a way I can check that?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Network Watcher variable packet capture allows you to create packet capture sessions to track traffic to and from a virtual machine. 
You may refer to these documentation links on network watcher: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-monitoring-overview
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-packet-capture-overview

Comment: Thanks!  I came across that yesterday.  If I understand correctly, though, that captures traffic between two known sources, right?  I mean, I'd have to know both endpoints for Network Watcher to be of effect, wouldn't I?

And regardless of the answer to the question about NW needing to know both endpoints, I do appreciate you taking the time to respond.